# How to extract data from a dataframe based on a variable in a certain column in R

Tags: r

If I have a data frame of option prices such as

```
mydata = read.csv("optionprices.csv")
print(mydata)

Symbol Price Volume
AAPL   100   20
AAPL   105   40
AMZN   300   30
AMZN   305   60
```

How can I can around extracting data to create another data frame where mydata$Symbol == "AAPL"? So that my new data frame is

```
Symbol Price Volume
AAPL   100   20
AAPL   105   40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  filter(Symbol == "AAPL") -> df_new

df_new

  Symbol Price Volume
1   AAPL   100     20
2   AAPL   105     40
```

Or using base R:

```
df_new <- subset(mydata, Symbol == "AAPL")
df_new

  Symbol Price Volume
1   AAPL   100     20
2   AAPL   105     40
```

Comment: Great stuff this worked a charm. thank you Anoushiravan!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Anoushiravan is great.

Antoher method using base r: `df[which(df$Symbol == "AAPL"),]`

```
df <- data.frame(Symbol = c("AAPL","AAPL","AMZN","AMZN"), 
                 Price=c("100","105","300","305"),
                 Volume=c("20","40","30","60"))

> df 
  Symbol Price Volume
1   AAPL   100     20
2   AAPL   105     40
3   AMZN   300     30
4   AMZN   305     60

new_df <- df[which(df$Symbol == "AAPL"),]

> new_df
  Symbol Price Volume
1   AAPL   100     20
2   AAPL   105     40
```

Comment: Unless you have NA's in the column the `which` function is not necessary for logical subsetting.

Comment: Thanks Anoushiravan! :D

Comment: Yes, Maximilian, that's true. I consider it good practice to use `which` in this way, although one might also say that it is good practice to check for NA's first... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you for the help lab_rat_kid!

Comment: Happy to help. Please pick an answer to close off the question, and upvote too! 